# Escape key close panel c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to close / hide the `panel` while pressing `escape` key?

I searched for `keydown` event in ***panel*** and it is not present.

Comment: _"I searched for keydown event in panel and it is not present"_ - [Guessed you missed this then](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=winforms+panel+keydown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panel control cant be focused so you cant handle key down event.
Try to handle key down event of parent control or in more broad way override `ProcessCmdKey` method:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // your logic here. For example:
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Escape:
             //do something
             break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: How to add logic of escape key pressed in the above code

Answer (score 1):

Handle the **Control** KeyPress/KeyDown event:

```
(Control)thePanel.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(ThePanel_KeyPress);

public void ThePanel_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape) ... // Do something
}
```